# How to create a string lookup in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a set of data that I probably best held in a table/matrix. It is a collection of match statistic from a game where two teams of 5 characters of over 100 character choices are available. No character can be picked twice in one match. What I'm trying to do I sum the number of times each character has killed other character over a whole batch of matches. What I imagine having is a table with all the characters on both the heading and the first column of the table. The value in each cell being how often the character of that row has killed the character of that column.

My problem is I have the data like this;

```
Tom    1 Sarah  4 Juliet  3 Joe
Dick   3 Sarah  2 Juliet  - Joe
Harry  1 Sarah  2 Juliet  5 Joe

Sarah  3 Tom    - Dick    1 Harry
Juliet 1 Tom    2 Dick    3 Harry
Joe    - Tom    4 Dick    - Harry
```

The first line means Tom has killed Sarah once, Juliet 4 times and Joe 3 time.

My problem is there is over 100 character names (Tom, Juliet etc.) so how do I store how many times Tom has killed Sarah without having a select case statement with 100 cases for each character? Ideally I'd like to just give each character a number and then have a square array and store the number like this;

```
dim kills(100,100) as integer
(1,23) +=1
(1,34) +=4
etc.
```

In the above (1,23) might be Tom killing sarah as Tom's ID may be 1 and Sarahs may be 23.

Comment: You would probably be better holding this kind of information in a database and record kills as transactions if you will. You could store all the people in a table and then record each time they kill some one else in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Linq expert but how about something like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Kills As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
    Dim Names As String = "Tom,Dick,Harry,John,Sarah,Jill"
    Dim NameArray = Names.Split(",")
    ' Create a dictionary of dictionaries to hold the kills
    For Each killer As String In NameArray
        Dim newKill As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        For Each victim As String In NameArray
            newKill.Add(victim, 0)
        Next
        Kills.Add(killer, newKill)
    Next

    ' Tom Kills Sarah
    Kills("Tom")("Sarah") += 1
    Kills("Tom")("Sarah") += 1
    ' Tom kills Jill
    Kills("Tom")("Jill") += 1
    Kills("Dick")("Tom") += 1
    Kills("Dick")("Sarah") += 1
    ' Get some numbers out
    Dim SarahDies = Kills.Sum(Function(k) k.Value("Sarah"))
    Dim JillDies = Kills.Sum(Function(k) k.Value("Jill"))
    Dim DickDies = Kills.Sum(Function(k) k.Value("Dick"))
    Dim TomKillsSarah = Kills("Tom")("Sarah")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution for consideration. Use a custom class to represent the tuple of killer/victim and use that as key in the `Dictionary`.

```
Public Class KillInfo
    Implements IEquatable(Of KillInfo)

    Public Property Killer As String
    Public Property Victim As String

    Public Sub New(killer As String, victim As String)
        Me.Killer = killer
        Me.Victim = victim
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return Killer.GetHashCode() Xor Victim.GetHashCode()
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing OrElse Me.GetType() IsNot obj.GetType() Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return Equals(DirectCast(obj, KillInfo))
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function Equals(other As KillInfo) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of KillInfo).Equals
        Return other.Killer.Equals(Killer) AndAlso other.Victim.Equals(Victim)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then use it like this

```
Dim Names As String = "Tom,Dick,Harry,John,Sarah,Jill"
Dim NameArray = Names.Split(",")

Dim KillSum As New Dictionary(Of KillInfo, Integer)

For Each killer As String In NameArray
    For Each victim As String In NameArray
        KillSum.Add(New KillInfo(killer, victim), 0)
    Next
Next

KillSum(New KillInfo("Tom", "Dick")) += 10
KillSum(New KillInfo("Tom", "Dick")) += 23
KillSum(New KillInfo("Harry", "Jill")) += 56
KillSum(New KillInfo("Jill", "Harry")) += 25

For Each info In KillSum
    Console.WriteLine($"{info.Key.Killer} killed {info.Key.Victim} {info.Value} times.")
Next
```

Note: I don't know if `Tuple(Of K,V)` would have implemented `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` on its own in a way that would be usable with a Dictionary, which is why I wrote the `KillInfo` class. If `Tuple` does in fact work like that, then you can skip my class and get right to the using part.